Linearity out of the Tensor Product of Vector Spaces
Let W, V finite dimensional vector spaces; Intending to show

$W \otimes V*  \to Hom(V,W) $ is a Isomorphism of vector spaces.

I found the explicit pairing on the Basis
$w_i \otimes v_j^* \to v_j^*(v) w$. However im stuck showing that this is a linear function. Im guessing that one could use the universal property of the tensor product, or is there a more direct way ?

In general to get arrows out of tensor products your best bet is the universal property. You get linearity (from multilinearity) for free.
